# System.NullReferenceException - why can't I bypass it with try-catch?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to debug the following situation.
I have some constants like this:

```
    public enum ACCESS_LEVEL
    {
        [Description("Organization")]
        ORGANIZATION = 1,
        [Description("Group")]
        GROUP = 2,
        [Description("User")]
        USER = 3
    }
```

And I have a method like this, which is supposed to return the description string:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
        {
            var attribute = value.GetType()
                .GetField(value.ToString())
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
            return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
        }
    }
```

Normally this would get called like `GetDescription(GROUP)` and return "Group".
I have a situation where someone has erroneously coded `GetDescription(0)`. That causes it to throw a System.NullReferenceException, which seems reasonable since there is no constant with a zero value. It looks to me like that last line had been intended to take care of this situation by returning the invalid value as a string, but execution never gets to that line because the exception is thrown in the complex Linq statement that I don't fully understand.

But here's my primary question: I tried putting this code in a try-catch but that didn't work either; the exception was still thrown and the catch block was just ignored. So why did try-catch not work?

I'm on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 16.8.3 and .NET 4.8.04084

Comment: `value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())` returns null for a non-existent `Enum` member (there cannot be a field called `0`)

Comment: _I tried putting this code in a try-catch but that didn't work either; the exception was still thrown and the catch block was just ignored._ show the code or it exists only in your mind.

Comment: try   var type=value.GetType(); if type is ok then  var attribute= type.GetField...and so on.

Comment: @Sergey I think that if `value != null`, then `value.GetType()` will succeed... But `value` could be `null` (`Enum` is a reference type)

Comment: @xanatos An enum value cannot be null. It is a value type like an int.

Comment: This is now I had the try-catch: `try {var attribute...; return attribute...;} catch (Exception e) {return "Err";)`

Comment: _"I tried putting this code in a try-catch but that didn't work either; the exception was still thrown and the catch block was just ignored"_ -- that doesn't happen. An exception thrown inside a `try` block _will_ be caught by a correctly-written `catch` block. Unfortunately, you neglected to post any sort of useful code example. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Is (Exception e) the problem?

Comment: @Sergey I used capital-case `Enum`, no lower-case `enum`. The OP wrote `this Enum value`, and there `value` can be null.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use null-conditional operator (`?`) to avoid the exception, like this:

```
 public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
 {
      var attribute = value.GetType()
                .GetField(value.ToString())? // <-- null-conditional operator
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
      return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
 }
```

Using the above, this line:

```
 ACCESS_LEVEL a = 0;           
 var t = a.GetDescription();
```

sets `t` to `"0"`

Comment: The code seems correct... but my OC side forces me to point out that splitting the `?` from the `.` is legal but horrible. I didn't even know you could split it! Is it the only two chars operator that you can split?

Comment: @xanatos Using `?` operator just terminates the expression evaluation, anything after the operator is not evaluated and null is returned, as the OP seems to want.

Comment: @xanatos `?.` can certainly be split. I do agree, though, it looks much better as `?.` than `? \n .`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto My surprise was that it is splittable. I don't remember other splittable 2 chars or 3 chars operators that are splittable. It is something curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        if (value == null) return "None"; // or throw exception
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type != typeof(ACCESS_LEVEL)) return "None"; // or throw exception
        var field = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        if (field == null) return "None"; // or throw exception

        var attribute = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
        .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }
}
```